# Masking an image using a shape with layer style in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, clipping-mask, layer-style, cc-2019

I am working on a UI design in Photoshop CC 2019. I have an image and I would like to mask it with a shape. Masking works fine with the shape. But if I applied some layer style like gradient or color overlay, then the masked images is overlayed by this gradient or color overlay.

If I convert the masking shape with gradient to smart object, masking will work. But I would like to know whether there any other ways to achieve this?

Since the UI is for 1x/2x/3x devices, I need resizing of the design without losing quality.

Comment: Use Layer Masks :) well im also UI designer and was frustrated with that issue. and for now to resolve it i use Layer masks on images instead of clipping it

Comment: Could you add some images with the problem you are referring to please?

Comment: @DesignPhoenix, I am using layer mask. But if there is a layer style like gradient-overlay or color-overlay for the masking shape, then it don't work.

Comment: Read my answer :) hope it helps!

Comment: Layer Masks works with All styles including Drop shadow ; Glows and gradients :) if it is transparent styles like drop shadow you have to duplicate shape and convert it to smart object in order to clip into drop shadows too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Layer Masks**

I also gone in same problem since I'm also UI designer and i came up with wrokaround like below image where i uses layer masks and using freeform move. Hope it helps!

[image]